# Sed command in perl script

Tags: bash, perl, unix, sed

I am trying to use sed command from my Perl script. I have to get the data of last hour from a file which is 25GB , but when i am running the same command from terminal it is working fine but the same command is not working from Perl script. System variable which i am using , that is causing the issue i think , don't know how to handle :

```
my $sed_cmd = 'sed -n "/'.$last_hour.'/,\$p"';
my $outstr=`ssh $remote_addr $sed_cmd  $dir/$remote_filename`;
```

Above command is getting converted like this : `sed -n "/15:12:24/,\$p"` and from perl script this not working.
But actually this command is working from terminal :  `sed -n "/15:09:40/,\$p"` file

the only diffrence is when i am calling this sed command with ssh i am geting error otherwise it is working fine . Could you please suggest what is the issue

Comment: perl can handle this, why call `sed`?

Comment: may be, `my $sed_cmd=quotemeta('sed -n "/'.$last_hour.'/,\$p"')`?

Comment: guys, he's sending the sed command to a remote host using ssh. Chill.

Comment: @anubhava , could you please suggest how we can do this from perl instead of using sed . I want to grep all those lines which are printed in last hour

Comment: @wolfrevokcats quotemeta worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into a bit of quoting hell with the backticks, where you need to concatenate the ssh command and all its arguments into a string to send to sh. I'd suggest this, where each component of the ssh command is a separate word:

```
use autodie;

my @ssh_cmd = ('ssh', $remote_addr, 'sed', '-n', "/$last_hour/,\\\$p", "$dir/$remote_filename");
open my $pipe, '-|', @ssh_cmd;
my $outstr = join '', <$pipe>;
close $pipe;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH). It would take care of doing the [shell escaping](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Shell-quoting) automatically:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($remote_addr);
my $outstr = $ssh->capture('sed', '-n', "/$last_hour/,\$p", "$dir/$remote_file");
```

BTW, reading a 25Gb file just to get some lines from the end may be inefficient and generate an appreciable IO load. Maybe you could use [tac](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html) which reads the file lines in reverse order:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($remote_addr);
my $fh = $ssh->pipe_out('tac', "$dir/$remote_file");
my @out;
while (<$fh>) {
    /$last_hour/ or last; # you may need to adjust this
                          # stop condition!
    unshift @out, $_;
}
close($fh);
```